# pandas - A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I know this has been asked before but my case is slightly different . I am using the below .

```
    train_mask = df_train['category_count'] == 3

    df_train.loc[train_mask]['cat1'] = df_train.loc[train_mask]['categories'][0[0]
    df_train.loc[train_mask]['cat2'] = df_train.loc[train_mask]['categories'][0][1]
    df_train.loc[train_mask]['cat3'] = df_train.loc[train_mask]['categories'][0][2]


where for eg : df_train['categories'] is a list  : ["Shirt","Trousers","Shoes"]
```

I am using the .loc method inspite of which i keep getting the below error .Can someone please explain why .

> C:\Users\sraghunath\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:1:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead

Comment: I think you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20625582/2901002)

Comment: So maybe need `df_train.loc[train_mask, 'cat1'] = df_train.loc[train_mask, 'categories'][0][0]`, but not sure with last `[0][0]`.

Comment: If it does not work or some problem, please add some sample data to question.

Comment: @jezrael - Perfect...guess i can't accept it as an answer since its a comment..but yes...many thanks for fixing my issue.

Comment: It is dupe, so I write only comment :(